# How to select multiple fields in MySQL query when using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

I want to select multiple fields from table p.

The second line of this code is wrong. how to write?

except `p.*`

I don't want `p.*`

```
SELECT
      p.id, title, price
      c.`title` as `CategoryTitle`
      from `tbl_products` p
      INNER JOIN `tbl_categories` c
      ON p.`category_FK` = c.`id`
```

Comment: Just like `p.id`: `p.name`, `p.someothercolumn` ...am I missing something?

Comment: that works, I thought maybe there is another way to not using multiple p.

Comment: Although it seems overly complicated, you can use your server language, if you're using one, to automate, or make dynamic, column selection.

Comment: You are missing a comma after price. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: @philipxy  It needed to be like p.id, p.title, p.price, I didn't know how to write this.in addition I didn't put comma too, but first form with comma didn't worked too.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Q&A are forever & to help others, please edit to a good presentation of 1 question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you might have your own reason so, perhaps you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
      id, title, price, CategoryTitle
   FROM `tbl_products` p
      INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT `title` AS 'CategoryTitle', id AS 'CategoryID' 
           FROM `tbl_categories`) c
      ON category_FK = CategoryID
```

Make one of the table as a subquery and define column alias that's not a duplicate with the other table. In your example, it seems like both of your tables have columns with similar names like `id` & `title`. Once you define those similar column names in the subquery with different alias, then you won't need to do `p.xx` or `c.xx`.